# Error then install android studio, i can't run app

Tags: android

Missing toolbar and fab in Mainactivity.java

How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: http://imgur.com/BgDwbhX my file XML

Comment: Your error is logic, you don't have toolbar/fab variable in your xml.

Comment: Try clean and rebuild your project

Comment: yes, thanks all. I can start my applycation :)